# Передача файла с невозможным именем по HTTP на сервер

Tags: http

Добрый день.
Задали вопрос: "Как отправить на сервер (по протоколу HTTP) файл с именем «**%^##76 / // \ ^^ [ ] : .jpg**»?"
Файл с таким именем ни в одной системе создать нельзя, но отправить можно. Каждый символ в имени критичен, ответ для файла с другим именем не подходит. Что с ним будет дальше - это за рамками вопроса.

Comment: Кодируйте подобные символы посредством «[Percent encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding#Character_data)». Кстати, существуют онлайн-инструменты(например, https://www.urlencoder.org/) для подобного кодирования/раскодирования.